# Django: defining a generic manager in an Abstract model

Tags: django, django-models

Using the following code and defining suitable `NATURAL_KEY` per every class fails (instead of defining different mangers in every class, which replicate the same code):

```
class NexchangeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, param):
        if param == "*":
            return self.all()
        lookup = {self.NATURAL_KEY: param}
        return self.get(**lookup)


class NexchangeModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    objects = NexchangeManager()
```

Djagno complains about fields replication, although NexhcnageModel is an Abstract model.
Should I use a mixin instead?

error:

```
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/beoleg/dev/nexchange/core/fixtures/pairs_cross.json': 'NexchangeManager' object has no attribute 'NATURAL_KEY': (core.pair:pk=1) field_value was '['LTC']'
```

The purpose of this, a bit overcomplicated code at first glance is, to have something like this in my fixtures:

```
[
  {
    "model": "payments.paymentpreference",
    "pk": 8,
    "fields": {
      "user": ["onit"],
      "identifier": "paypal@nexchange.co.uk",
      "payment_method": 12,
      "comment": "Please send the funds as a personal payment (this is a precaution to prevent charge backs, payments for goods and services will be automatically declined)",
      "currency": [
          ["*"]
      ],
      "created_on":"2016-11-01T17:41:28+00:00",
      "modified_on":"2016-11-01T17:41:28+00:00"
    }
  }
]
```

Instaed of:

```
[
  {
    "model": "payments.paymentpreference",
    "pk": 8,
    "fields": {
      "user": ["onit"],
      "identifier": "paypal@nexchange.co.uk",
      "payment_method": 12,
      "comment": "Please send the funds as a personal payment (this is a precaution to prevent charge backs, payments for goods and services will be automatically declined)",
      "currency": [
         ["USD"],
         ["RUB"],
         ["EUR"],
         ["GBP"],
         ["JPY"],
         ["HRK"],
         ["CHF"],
         ["PLN"],
         ["RON"],
         ["BGN"],
         ["CZK"],
         ["AUD"],
         ["CAD"],
         ["NOK"],
         ["SEK"],
         ["DKK"],
         ["HUF"],
         ["TRY"],
         ["ZAR"],
         ["NZD"],
         ["BRL"],
         ["IDR"],
         ["ILS"],
         ["INR"],
         ["KRW"],
         ["MXN"],
         ["MYR"],
         ["PHP"],
         ["THB"]
      ],
      "created_on":"2016-11-01T17:41:28+00:00",
      "modified_on":"2016-11-01T17:41:28+00:00"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Fails how? Show the actual error. And show an example of how and where you're defining NATURAL_KEY.

Comment: @DanielRoseman edited! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the way you write your manager. If the `NATURAL_KEY` is an attribute of each model, I would write:

```
class NexchangeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, param):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        if param == "*":
           return qs.all()
        lookup = {qs.model.NATURAL_KEY: param}
        return qs.filter(**lookup)
```

Comment: django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/beoleg/dev/nexchange/core/fixtures/pairs_cross.json': 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id': (core.pair:pk=1) field_value was '['BTC']'

Answer (score 0):

Note: this answer is based on albars answer, but improved for allowing pk params.

manager:

```
class NexchangeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, param):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        if param == "*":
            return self.all()
        lookup = {qs.model.NATURAL_KEY: param}
        return self.get(**lookup)
```

Generic `Model` class:

```
class NexchangeModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    objects = NexchangeManager()
```